# Python method: How to accept a single object or a collection as parameter?

Tags: python

I'm wondering why I cannot find any solution to this by googling:
I want to write a python function which can accept either a single object or any collection of the same type. My idea is to wrap a list around the parameter if it is a single instance, like so:

```
def postprocess(results):
    """ An arbitrary function that takes a list or single object
        and behaves smart depending on that. """
    if not is_collection(results): # <-- How to implement this??
        results = [results]

    for result in results:
        # do processing magic
        print(result)

# to be called like one of those:
postprocess(result1)            # single object
postprocess([result1, result2]) # a list
postprocess((result1, result2)) # a tuple
```

What is the best/most pythonic way to implement `is_collection()`? (Might it bring problems, if `result` is an iterable type itself?

I could do `if type(results) is not list:`, but I explicitly want to allow any kind of iterable collection not only `list`.

Comment: Can you provide multiple examples of how `postprocess` can be called? Thank you.

Comment: You could `try` iterating over it, and assume it's not a collection if you can't (`except TypeError:`). The only problem there might be if `results` could be a string, which is both iterable and usually considered a value.

Comment: How would I implement the `try` and `except TypeError` version to execute the inner part of the loop on the single object without duplicating code?

Comment: def is_collection(unknown_type):
 return isinstance(unknown_type, collections.Iterable)